# separating clients' actions when using socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm new to socket.io, so I need some help. I'm building a tic-tac-toe game using socket.io and I want it to be played by two people on an ngrok server. I want the player that runs the server(me) to play for X and the player that connects to the server to play for O and I also need them to take turns. I can't figure out how to implement that, so I'd be very grateful if someone helps. The snippets of code that are responsible for that are below.

The function that handles a move:

```
handleClick(i) {
const squares = this.state.squares;

if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
  return;
}
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
buttons[i].classList.add('flip');
squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
let index = i;
const step = {
  squares: squares,
  xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
  number: index,
  toggleSound: true
};
this.state.xIsNext
? this.socket.emit('moveX', step)
: this.socket.emit('moveO', step)
}
```

Server:

```
socket.on('moveX', step => {
socket.broadcast.emit('moveX', {
  squares: step.squares,
  xIsNext: step.xIsNext,
  number: step.number,
  toggleSound: step.toggleSound
})
})
socket.on('moveO', step => {
socket.broadcast.emit('moveO', {
  squares: step.squares,
  xIsNext: step.xIsNext,
  number: step.number,
  toggleSound: step.toggleSound
})
})
```

Code from my component:

```
componentDidMount () {
    this.socket.on('moveX', step => {
    this.setState({
    squares: step.squares,
    xIsNext: step.xIsNext,
    toggleSound: step.toggleSound
  })
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
  buttons[step.number].classList.add('flip');
})
this.socket.on('moveO', step => {
  this.setState({
    squares: step.squares,
    xIsNext: step.xIsNext,
    toggleSound: step.toggleSound
  })
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
  buttons[step.number].classList.add('flip');
})
}
```

Comment: You can't figure out how to implement turns? Why not to store last turn at you server ad broadcast only opposite turn?

Comment: Yep, that's what I want. Sounds like a good idea.